# Tycho error with bundle requirement

Tags: maven, tycho

I'm using a tycho to make a build process.

This project is a RCP application, with tycho 0.21.0 and Java 1.6 compiler.

This project uses the europa plugins and features, to solve this I used featuresandbundles publisher and I put this files in Nexus.

In my project I have:

aggregator_project
parent_project
feature_project
repository_project

I am sending you attached the pom's projects.

When I execute the command mvn clean install, tycho shows the error below:

```
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.soluzionasf.zeus 1.0.0
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.soluzionasf.zeus 1.0.0 requires 'bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 1.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 1.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.bdi 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.bdi.lib 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.bdi.ui 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.common 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.common.lib 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.common.ui 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.fieldservice.lib 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.igeautils 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.operation.lib 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.operation.ui.common 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 1.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.bdi 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.bdi.lib 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.bdi.ui 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.common 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.common.lib 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.common.ui 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.fieldservice.lib 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.igeautils 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.operation.lib 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.operation.ui.common 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 1.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.bdi 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.bdi.lib 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.bdi.ui 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.common 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.common.lib 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.common.ui 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.fieldservice.lib 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.igeautils 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.operation.lib 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from com.soluzionasf.zeus.operation.ui.common 1.0.0 to bundle com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common 0.0.0.; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.AbstractResolutionStrategy.newResolutionException(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve(ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.AbstractResolutionStrategy.resolve(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.doResolveDependencies(P2DependencyResolver.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.resolveDependencies(P2DependencyResolver.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:274)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
```

**Feature.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>zeus.parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../com.example.zeus.parent</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>zeus.feature</artifactId>
    <packaging>eclipse-feature</packaging>

</project>
```

**Repository.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>zeus.repository</artifactId>
    <packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>zeus.parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../com.example.zeus.parent</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <win32>zip</win32>
                        <linux>tar.gz</linux>
                        <macosx>tar.gz</macosx>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>materialize-products</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>materialize-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>archive-products</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>archive-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[parent.xml](https://mega.nz/#!sockVDyC!wi8es0vAYQAWHQ8i7drb2PXqxLBTedVKbQh4Voz05MQ)
[aggregator.xml](https://mega.nz/#!N1dGSbQZ!DVBXN9BPxO7supGVCx9_VlIoP1XoZM6cdnZZhfMdJ-A)

Has someone any ideia to solve this?

Comment: How do you declare dependency to com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common? Do you use "Required Plugins' or "Imported packages"

Comment: I'm new on this subject, but I will try to explain. From what I understand I have all the dependencies of control on the MANIFEST file.

But the dependencies are also within the pluguin.xml file.

In this case have a project called com.soluzionasf.zeus depending on the com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the error reason:

Accessing the project com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common and opening the pom.xml file, I identified that it was like this:

```
<groupId> com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common </ groupId>
<artifactId> com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common </ artifactId>
<version> 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT </ version>
<packaging> jar </ packaging>
```

And the correct is:

```
<groupId> com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common </ groupId>
<artifactId> com.soluzionasf.arqw10.common </ artifactId>
<version> 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT </ version>
<packaging> eclipse-plugin </ packaging>
```